# Rails 4, Carrierwave, Jcrop, image upload and resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

**UPDATE**
I moved the crop code from the uploader directly to the Notebook Model so that it gets called at least. Now, the image is getting processed. It's getting cropped in fact, to the correct width and height dimensions, but the x and y offsets are wrong. I'm using MiniMagick, not RMagick. Here is my crop_image method:

```rb
def crop_image
    if crop_x.present?
        image.manipulate! do |img|
            x = crop_x.to_i
            y = crop_y.to_i
            w = crop_w.to_i
            h = crop_h.to_i

            z = "#{w}x#{h}+#{x}+#{y}"
            img.resize "600x600"
            img.crop(z)
            img
        end
    end
    image.resize_to_fill(224, 150)
end
```

---

Has something changed in Rails 4 with regards to carrierwave or imagemagick? I copied over code that I had working (in a Rails 3 application) to upload an image, crop it, and save both versions, but I can't get it to work in the Rails 4 app.

Here are the relevant parts:

```rb
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :access, presence: true
    mount_uploader  :image, ImageUploader
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :invites
    attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
    after_update    :crop_image

    def notebook_title
        title
    end

    def user_name
        user.name
    end

    def crop_image
        image.recreate_versions! if crop_x.present?
    end
end
```

And the recreate_versions! call accesses the image_uploader

```rb
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  include Sprockets::Rails::Helper

  storage :file

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :large do
    process resize_to_limit: [600, 600]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :crop
    resize_to_fill(224, 150)
  end

  def err
    raise "error here"
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(600, 600)

      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i

        size = w << 'x' << h
        offset = '+' << x << '+' << y

        img.crop("#{size}#{offset}") 
        img
      end
     end
  end
end
```

I'm seeing values for crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, and crop_h. The version :thumb block does not seem to call any process methods. Even if I try to raise an error from inside the version :thumb block, it doesn't work.

If anyone can provide any info that would be great.